# Running NextCloud on HTTPS/SSL with LetsEncrypt

Tags: pi-3, apache-httpd, sudo, root, nextcloud

I have successfully installed Nextcloud on a Pi3 using snap

`sudo snap install nextcloud`.

Confirmation follows promptly:

`nextcloud 15.0.10snap3 from Nextcloud✓ installed`

.

Now this tutorial: https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Enabling-HTTPS-(SSL,-TLS) tells me is I can get it to run on HTTPS with LetsEncrypt with just this single command:

`sudo nextcloud.enable-https lets-encrypt`

However the command is not found:

`sudo: nextcloud.enable-https: command not found`

The interesting thing is, that when running it as non-root, I get this:

`ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
This utility needs to run as root`

The above is output eight times btw.

So, in summary, as non-root I get a `execute as root` but as root I get a `not found`.

What's going on and how can I get LetsEncrypt SSL to work with my NextCloud?

Comment: run `which nextcloud.enable-https` and `sudo which nextcloud.enable-https` - is it the same output?

Comment: Good stuff, it was not in the PATH. Thanks.